# How to programmatically modify Sharepoint content properties from InfoPath?

Tags: c#, sharepoint, infopath

I have an InfoPath form that submits to a Sharepoint document library.  There is some metadata that is accessible through the "Edit Properties" menu if you click on the uploaded form in the document library.  To be specific we have 3 fields: Content Type, File Category, and File Sub-Category.  I want to be able to set these fields automatically when the form is submitted.  How can this be accomplished using the Sharepoint web services or DOM?  Thanks.

- Jared

Comment: Is the user submitting the form responsible for providing the field values?

Answer (score 2):

Editing a inbuild properties like Content Type etc are not possible but if you have some meta data in the Form that needs to be edited, yes it is possible and it is called Property Promotion

Refer [this](http://blog.ksenthil.net/archive/2009/07/25/promoting-properties-e28093-expose-infopath-fields-as-site-columns.aspx) link for more details

Comment: looks like hyperlink is broken!